# remove marker in google map v2 when location change more than 10m

Tags: android, google-maps

To put marker on current location i use onLocationChange. But if device move more than 10m i want to remove that marker and i don't want new marker to come. Please someone help.
I put marker in current location like this:
here is my code

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position").snippet(act);
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getBitmap(imagePath,1)));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);


    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(initialZoom));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why you invoke removeLocationUpdates? after this call you haven't more update

Comment: i don't want to consume more data of user device, that's why. If i'm wrong please correct me because i'm a beginner.